# Integrate Jetpack Compose in existing project

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I'm trying to add compose to my project and encountered this issue:

> ```
> org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.BackendException: Backend Internal error: Exception during IR lowering
> File being compiled: /Users/admin/app/src/main/java/ro/.../DeviceInputFragment.kt
> The root cause java.lang.AssertionError was thrown at: org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.ir.IrUtilsKt.copyValueParametersToStatic(IrUtils.kt:264)....
> ```

I have the following configuration:

- Target and compile sdk set to 32
- composeOptions {
  kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion "1.1.1"
  }
- kotlinVersion = '1.6.10'
- classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.4'
- kotlinOptions {
  jvmTarget = "1.8"
  useIR = true
  }
- buildFeatures {
  compose = true
  }

> composeVersion = "1.1.1"
>
> ```
>     implementation "androidx.compose.runtime:runtime:$composeVersion"
>     implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui:$composeVersion"
>     implementation "androidx.compose.foundation:foundation:$composeVersion"
>     implementation "androidx.compose.foundation:foundation-layout:$composeVersion"
>     implementation "androidx.compose.material:material:$composeVersion"
>     implementation "androidx.compose.runtime:runtime-livedata:$composeVersion"
>     implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:$composeVersion"
> ```

Maybe you can provide some suggestions.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue, and still cannot find how to solve it :/

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you add these lines in your android block in build.gradle

```
android {
 ... 

    buildFeatures {
       compose true
    }
    composeOptions {
       kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion '1.0.4'//change this value
       kotlinCompilerVersion '1.5.31' // change this value
    }
}
```

2. Make sure you do not have composable value initialization in the init block of a class
3. if nothing works. Delete .gradle .idea and Invalidate Caches and restart